# How do I handle roadblocks at work better? Should I complain to the boss, soldier through or wait for the problems to be resolved?

Tags: conflict-resolution

For example, I am a frontend developer. I build the client-facing web application in my company.

However for a lot of things I build, I need the data from the backend to come to me correctly. If it does not, I usually ping the backend developer and let him know that the server is broken or something. The backend developer does his magic, unclogs the app, lets the data to flow so that I can get on with my work.

But sometimes, this backend support is not available and I'm forced to work in the dark.

Now technically, I can continue with the work if I mock the data, add scaffolds in my code base or do some other trickery. But doing all this is usually more work than the effort it takes to complete the actual task.

Consequently, every time I hit a blocker at work, I find myself in between a rock and a hard place. Should I ping the backend guy to fix his thing or should I build the mocks and scaffolds? What if I get started with these mocks/scaffolds and by the time I'm done, the backend guy fixes his stuff on his end? In that case wouldn't the effort put in to build these mocks/scaffolds be wasted?

---

Another example would be in the military. You are a foot-soldier who needs an airlift to get to the other side of the mountain. But for some reason, the pilot isn't available. Maybe he is sleeping. Maybe he has diarrhea. In that case, what should I do? Should I wait for the next pilot to be available or just suck it up, climb the cliff and get to the other side? What if this sort of "unavailability" keeps happening repeatedly? Should I complain to the boss, suck it up and keep doing my job or reprimand the pilot?

Comment: This isn't really a "workplace" oriented comment, but I think you'd do well to create those mocks and scaffolds to benefit your development process in general and for testing! Don't think of it as a waste of time but instead as effort invested to get the benefit later...

Comment: This type of issue is one of the main reasons for the team to have daily standups - to raise any blockers. Also, dev servers aren't expected to have the same SLA as production, but it's not unreasonable to expect that it doesn't need regular intervention to keep it running either. Lastly, I agree with @seventyeightist, you should have some kind of mocking or similar ability for testing your code regardless.

Answer (score 3):

You should take the situation to your manager. You should indicate your intention to continue getting your job done, and then you should advocate for a different process (or potentially a data set) that frees you from being dependent on this ask and frees them from being interrupted with your requests.

The only real way to affect change for yourself is to have the process modified.

Comment: It works temporarily but what if it becomes a norm? Do I have to keep bugging the manager and backend developers for a dataset while none of this would have been necessary on the off chance that the APIs work?

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj: If you get your own manner of creating/maintaining a data set then you should be permanently freed of having to bug anyone for that stuff. My recommendation isn't for a temporary solution, it's to empower you to be able to do these things yourself.

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj do you already know what the datasets ought to look like? I assume yes since you said you "technically" can mock that data, which must mean you know what you're expecting to have in there. As such, I'd suggest (in line with this answer) that what you could take to your manager is an outline for how you could generate that dataset, estimated amount of time it would take (if it's non-trivial) etc, rather than just go to the manager with the stated problem. Or if it's a trivial amount of time, a "demo" of the mocked data for approval/confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to all examples is the same.

- Proceed as long as you can safely do so
- Notify all concerned (including both superiors, as well as colleges Where their work is dependent on your work)
- Have other tasks/projects to work on when you are blocked completely.

Communication, preparedness, and improvisation are the holy trinity of dealing with work blockages.

Comment: "Have other tasks/projects to work on when you are blocked completely."

This is excellent food for thought and is something I'd seriously consider.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when you're not given enough resources to do the job or there are massive obstacles to completion with no explanation given, that usually means you're expected to come up with a plan to resolve these deficiencies.

You should see this as an opportunity.

From the point of view of your boss, they don't want to have to orchestrate and setup every detail for each of their reports so that they can just "do their specific job".

From your point of view it may look like you're being hanged out to dry. But what it really means you have some amount of latitude to deal with the problems in front of you even if they're "not your job".

So, yes, go reach out to those backend folks and tell them what you need and why. Get yourself into the meetings of other groups so you can join forces with them and collaborate, communicate with other people's bosses if you need to. If you go too far, someone will alert you and you can just tell them that you're proactively trying to unblock some problem. This will be seen in a very positive light in most places even if sometimes they need to rein you in.

This is the kind of behavior that gets called "being a self-starter", you can remember these incidents and recall them during a behavioral interview as an example. This is perhaps one of the most desirable traits in professional employees. It means you'll need to deal with some conflict but that's part of the job.